# Resizing image when projecting into a TV my python tkinter code

Tags: python, interface, tkinter

I am trying to project my laptop screen into a 52" TV. I need the background image to fill the entire screen (independent of the size of the TV in which I am projecting). The window is able to resize when projecting, but the image does not. What I am missing ?

I am using python and tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file= r"a.gif")
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.focus_set()  # <-- move focus to this widget
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())

canvas = Canvas(root) #, width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=root.winfo_screenheight())
canvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='True') 
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')

w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Images are a specific size. If you want the image to grow or shrink you'll have to manually adjust the image yourself when the window resizes. Tkinter  can only halve or double the size of an image. For anything fancier you'll need something like PIL or pillow.

Since you know the maximum size is (I'm guessing) an HD display, you should probably start with an image that is 1920x1080 and then scale it down when you aren't projecting.